# psql - How do you query the last record relative to a matched row within a time window?

Tags: database, time, psql, querying

psql - How do you query the last record relative to a matched row within a time window?

The relative time window would be <= 20min from the row where the 4th column is equal to "true". I'm trying to get that matched row (4th column is true) AND the most recent row on the same key (email address) that contains a false in the 4th column, which has a time that's less than 20 minutes prior to the matched row time.

My sample table:

```
jon@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:30pm, true, data
jon@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:24pm, false, data
jon@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:21pm, false, data
jon@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:30pm, true, data
jon@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:24pm, false, data
jon@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:24pm, false, data
jon@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:30pm, true, data
danny@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:31pm, true, data
danny@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:22pm, false, data
stew@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:41pm, true, data
stew@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:18pm, false, data
```

What I am trying to get:

```
jon@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:30pm, true, data
jon@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:24pm, false, data
danny@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:31pm, true, data
danny@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:22pm, false, data
stew@gmail.com, 100.100.100.10, 5:41pm, true, data
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. The opening statement is illogical. The relative time window would be <= 20min from "true" : true is not a time - nothing can be 20 minutes from true. try rewording your request into plain English and then write your query from that.

Comment: When I referred to "true", I was referring to the row containing "true" in the 4th column. If you looked at the example, it would have cleared this up. In any case I modified the original question.

Comment: "The relative time window would be <= 20min from the row where the 4th column is equal to "true". " All of the records for Jon@gmail are within 20 minutes of all the true records. What do you mean by "last record" - do you mean most recent? Sounds like you need to write two queries - one to get the first record, and the next to get the most recent match - that could be done like so `select * from table where time between start and finish order by time desc limit 1` - that is pseudo code BTW